# How to delete row using jqgrid php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
$("#list2").jqGrid(
  {
    url:'getNew.php',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames:['ID','Name', 'Email'],
    colModel:[
      {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
      {name:'name',index:'name asc', width:100},
      {name:'email',index:'email', width:80, align:"right"},
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    height:'auto',
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example",
    editable: true,
    width: 1000,
  },
  'JSON'
);

$("#list2").navGrid("#pager2", { edit: true, add: true, del: true });

});
```

How to use this statement?
Calling:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('delGridRow', row_id_s,options );
```

How to delete row using jqgrid? Thanks for answering me

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?